# adding li to ul with loop in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

Hi i'm using jquery mobile and i'm adding `<li>` to `<ul>` but i don t get why it doesn t work,`<li>` not adding well i followed this http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/HuKab/

looks like the problem comes from the div

**Code:**

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

    var htmlText = '<li><div style="float:left"><br/><img src="images/steto.png" alt="image" /></div><div style="float:right"><br/><strong>'+i+' aaaaaaaa  </strong><p> '+i+' zzzzzzz : '+i+' zzzzzzzzz<br/> zzzzzzz : <br/> '+i+' RPPS : '+i+' zzzzzzzz </p></div></li>';

    $('ul').append(htmlText);
}
$('ul').listview('refresh');
```

An image http://hpics.li/b00407e

P.S. : when i do that in html directly it works fine and when i just had one it's work and place well
thanks for help
sry for english

Comment: have you given your `ul` the attribute `data-role="listview"`

Comment: use simple HTML inside `li` and use CSS not _inline_ styling http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/NLrLp/

Comment: yes <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="enter a name ..." data-inset="false" data-split-icon="gear" data-divider-theme="a"> strangely it doesn't work, i have this result http://hpics.li/22089f8 the second div still make it bug

Comment: when i tape in the research, it correct the problem, after searching when jquery forget to add a class `class="ui-li-static ui-body-inherit` i added it in my `<li>` and it works now ... thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **trigger( "create" )** with the **$('ul').append(htmlText)** as follow:

## Example

```
   $('ul').append(htmlText).trigger( "create" );
```

hope it will work.

### If it works don't forget to VOTE

## Thank you